# Problem inserting LWC to display Account data using wire APEX method

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components

Created a LWC to display Account Record data using the APEX wire method, after pushing the code to the scratch org, unable to add the LWC onto the record page as unable to open the 'Account's record page in edit mode'.There is no 'edit page' option under 'Setup'. Only 'edit object' option available.
Please help me out, Thanks in advance.

[image]

Below is the code

.js code

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getAccountList from '@salesforce/apex/GetAccountData.getAccountList';

export default class LWCWireEx extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getAccountList) accounts;
}
```

.html code

```
<template>
        <lightning-card title="Apex Class Example(lWCWireEx compo)" icon-name="custom:custom63">
                <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                    <template if:true={accounts.data}>
                        <template for:each={accounts.data} for:item="acc">
                            <p key={acc.Id}>{acc.Name}</p>
                        </template>
                    </template>

                </div>
            </lightning-card>
    </template>
```

GetAccountData.cls APEX code

```
public with sharing class GetAccountData {
   @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Account> getAccountList() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name,Type,Rating,Phone FROM Account];
    }
}
```

Comment: You can modify record pages using Setup -> Lightning App Builder -> Account Record Page. Also , ensure that "isExposed" is true and Record page target is added in LWC meta file.

Comment: It seems like you are using custom visualforce page for account record page, could you change it to standard and then try again?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes to **js-meta.xml** file.

In targets tag, you need to mention where all you need to expose your LWC.
Unless you do this, components won't be visible in Edit Page section.

Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="">
    <apiVersion>46.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Also you can modify record pages using Setup -> Lightning App Builder -> Account Record Page, if 'Edit Page' option isn't visible.

Answer (score 0):

You do not get that option when there is classic override in **view** action:

[image]

AND when there are NO lightning record pages. In view action **Edit**:

[image]

> **You should create new lightning page (option shown in setup) and assign it as org default (or as per requirement)**

[image]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Created a new Lightning Account record page, was trying to drag and drop the above LWC onto this page but this throws below error (click this link to view the screenshot of the error. https://bit.ly/2E37Xid